# UDP connection timeout setting

Tags: dns, nginx

I am using nginx to proxy my own DNS server. On some websites like ndtv.com, I noticed that the browser's progress bar gets stuck about half way through though the website is fully downloaded and working.

I suspect this below could be cause of this:

```
2017/07/20 10:33:46 [info] 26445#26445: *102806 udp client
  <dns_client_ip>:12869 connected to 0.0.0.0:53
2017/07/20 10:33:46 [info] 26445#26445: *102806 udp proxy 127.0.0.1:55538 
  connected to 127.0.0.1:5053
2017/07/20 10:43:46 [info] 26445#26445: *102806 disconnected on shutdown
```

Notice how it takes 10 minutes for the connection to be closed @ 10:43:46. Is there a way to close the UDP connection as soon as the reply has been sent?

I have sudo grepped all the .conf files under /etc for the keyword timeout and manually reviewed if any timeout setting looks like it could be responsible for the 10 minute delay but no luck.

Comment: UDP is connectionless. There can't and never will be any timeout settings for this kind of protocol.

Comment: According to this link, UDP is "connectionless" in that no prior handshake is required between the client and the server before exchanging information. My interpretation is that since both sides have an IP and port, they are "connected" in the colloquial sense, not the networking sense. Happy to be corrected though. I'm figuring this out as I go along.

http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/connectionless

Comment: This could be a false alarm because I am definitely reloading nginx every minute.

http://marc.info/?l=nginx&m=144554796126888&w=2